# Copia Items de listBox1 a ListBox2 en Visual Basic 10

Tags: vb.net

Quiero copiar los items de una listbox a otra y que al copiarlos se borren de la primera, alguna idea de cómo puedo lograrlo? hasta el momento se borra la listbox 1 y queda sin copiar.Esto es lo qué he intentado.

```
Sub copiar()
        For Each item As Object In Me.R_10s.Items

            Me.Copia.Items.Add(item)

        Next
            Me.Copia.Items.Clear()
            Me.R_10s.Items.Clear()
     End Sub
```

Comment: Deberias agregar el codigo de lo que has intentado.

Comment: Claro, ya  lo edité.

Comment: Intenta quitar esta linea: `Me.Copia.Items.Clear()`

Comment: hacele caso a @alanfcm que eses es tu problema. si no entendes porque, ponemos una respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a Poner-los en Orden:

```html
Sub copiar()
  Me.Copia.Items.Clear()
  For Each item As Object In Me.R_10s.Items
     Me.Copia.Items.Add(item)
  Next
  Me.R_10s.Items.Clear()
End Sub
```